# Flask-SocketIO eventlet cannot switch to a different thread

Tags: python, multithreading, eventlet, flask-socketio

The project I'm currently working on uses Flask-SocketIO to communicate between my Raspberry Pi and clients connecting to the website it serves. However, an error occurs once I set up one or more extra threads. I used a monkey patch to allow a background thread (this works). But when I start up another one to handle a specific event, the program crashes. These are the core files currently:

`apps.py`

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()

from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
sio = SocketIO(app, async_mode="eventlet")
```

`main.py`

```
import apps
import other_module
import another_module    

from threading import Thread

from flask_socketio import emit

@apps.sio.on("problematic")
def this_is_problematic(data):
    Thread(target=other_module.run).start()

def updates():
    while True:
        apps.sio.emit("data", another_module.data())
        time.sleep(.3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Thread(target=updates).start()
    apps.sio.run(apps.app, host="0.0.0.0")
```

The `other_module` will frequently emit events to all clients during the execution of its `run` method (which may run for minutes, but sleeps frequently), so I assume it has something to do with that. The `apps` module is defined seperately to avoid such otherwise cyclic dependencies. This is the error I get while `other_module` is executing its `run` method, nothing more and nothing less:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 457, in fire_timers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/hubs/timer.py", line 58, in __call__
    cb(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/semaphore.py", line 145, in _do_acquire
    waiter.switch()
error: cannot switch to a different thread
```

**Edit:** It looks like the error occurs whenever I try to use my PiCamera in a different thread. I already tried importing it safely using `eventlet.import_patched("picamera")`, but without any success. Should I fall back to `async_mode="threading"`?

Comment: Try monkey patching eventlet in your main file, above all your imports.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. I think it might have something to do with the `other module` spawning another thread itself (for a `PiCamera` capturing continuously during its `run` method). I have some other events setting up a new thread, and these work just fine.

Comment: I think you should make sure the monkey patching is working in the entire application. My understanding is that this error you are getting occurs when mixing regular and green threads.

Comment: I tried importing every external library I use with `eventlet.import_patched`. The error however only occurs when the `PiCamera` is running. I tried moving the setup of the camera thread from the `run` method to the `main.py` module, but again without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolate the problem. If it works without PiCamera, then right now your best option is either:

- async-mode=threading
- PiCamera in separate process and communicate via sockets

Comment: I'll try it, but I think the possible gain in performance won't beat its increased complexity. I can just fall back to `async-mode="threading"` and deal with it in a simple way.

Comment: Threading is performance. Separate process is a workaround for problems.

Comment: I meant the gain in performance of being able to keep using `eventlet`, but it seems like falling back to the `async-mode="threading"` works best for me.